# Excel Picking random numbers with IF statement and creating random arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a list of random numbers that don't duplicate and then I want to take those numbers and generate multiple lists that are all random.

```
for example
for cells A1-A10 i want random numbers from 1-100
and then for A11-20 I want random numbers from 1-100
and then for A21 - A30 I want random number from 1-100
```

dragging down and repeating this seems possible with the MOD and OFFSET function which I'm still learning about.

For generating numbers I've tried

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)
```

but it produces duplicates.

Ive also tried
Putting

```
Rand()
```

in G1 and generating random numbers
and then using

```
=RANK.EQ(G1,$G$1:$G$100)
```

along with:

```
=INDEX($H$1:$H$100, RANK(G1,$G$1:$G$100), 1)
```

which is better and doesn't produce duplicates but since i need multiple lists what happens is every list has the exact same data since the code is just replicating the same reference.

e.g : what i get is A1-10

```
A1 = 65
A2 = 54
A3 = 23
A4 = 31
A10= 23
```

then i try repeat the code for A11 - A 20
but it produces the same values.

even if i use

```
=INDEX($H$1:$H$50, RANK.EQ(G2, $G$1:$G$100) + COUNTIF($G$1:G2, G2) - 1, 1)
```

and then i have

```
=INDEX($H$1:$H$100, RANK(G1,$G$1:$G$100), 1)
```

in two differnt rows they produce the exact same random numbers

So i reckoned I need something that randomises every time.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Lots of questions on here about random numbers - have you looked? Also consider looking for dealing with duplicates...

Comment: Is a **VBA** solution acceptable ??

Comment: sure gary, anything helps. I will give it a try!

Comment: been reading for a few hours, cant find something that really fits. A lot of people give the rank() option as a solution but it doesnt work for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following VBA macro:

```
Sub vRandom()
    Dim mn As Long, mx As Long, samples As Long
    Dim times As Long, arr1(), t As Long, s As Long
    Dim k As Long

    mn = 1
    mx = 100
    samples = 10
    times = 3
    k = 1

    ReDim arr1(mn To mx)
    For s = mn To mx
            arr1(s) = s
    Next s

    For t = 1 To times

        Call Shuffle(arr1)
        For s = 1 To samples
            Cells(k, 1) = arr1(mn + s - 1)
            k = k + 1
        Next s
    Next t

End Sub
Public Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, J As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, Temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For i = Low To Hi
        Helper(i) = Rnd
    Next i


    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

The code produces **3** blocks of items *(10 items in each block)*.

**Within** a block there are no duplicates, but there may be duplicates **between** blocks.

Comment: Gary's it worked incredibly! thanks for the time and effort, I truly appreciate it. Ive been sitting around all day trying all kinds of formulas and everything just fell apart. Thanks